# 'HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'CreateResponse' and no accessible extension method

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

The below is my code. It looks HttpRequest could not able to access CreateResponse. Kindly help.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Abc.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]

    public class PaymentController : Controller
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Post()
        {
            // ... do the job

            // now redirect
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri("http://www.abcmvc.com");
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HttpResponseMessage` and `Request.CreateResponse` are legacy ways to produce a HTTP response from older ASP.NET days, which do not apply to ASP.NET Core. If you have an ASP.NET Core application, you should use the mechanisms of ASP.NET Core, in particular the action results, to produce responses.

In your case, if you want to produce a redirect to some other location, then you can do it like this in ASP.NET Core:

```
public IActionResult Post()
{
    // ... do the job

    return RedirectPermanent("http://www.abcmvc.com");
}
```

This uses the [`RedirectPermanent` utility method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirectpermanent?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to create a [`RedirectResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.redirectresult?view=aspnetcore-3.1).